# What's the difference between a lymphocyte and a plasma cell?

Tags: immunology, hematology, lymphatic-system

According to my understanding, lymphocytes is the broad terminology for both T lymphocytes as well as B lymphocytes, while plasma cells refers to mature B cells which produce antibodies. But then why are they mentioned separately, doesn't a plasma cell come under category of lymphocyte?

Comment: *But then why are they mentioned separately*, where are they mentioned separately? If you are referring to a specific text or quote that raises this question, it would be best to include that reference here. right now your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes, in Robbin's Basic Pathology, while describing inflammatory process of several diseases, it is mentioned that there is presence of both plasma cells as well as lymphocytes in the affected tissue. So that raises the question, why are plasma cells and lymphocytes mentioned separately? Why not just mention that there was infiltrate of lymphocytes (assuming that plasma cells come under a category of lymphocytes)?